# How to make JSON.stringify output getters of an object by using decorators?

Tags: angular, typescript, getter, typescript-decorator

I need the `JSON.stringify` method to output getters. I understand that it's not doing this because getters are not "enumerable".

I found a solution for that and I am using `Object.defineProperty` to greater the getter with an enumerable property as shown in the [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(this%2C%20%27location%27%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enumerable%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20get%3A%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%27Hello%20from%20Getetr!%27%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Main%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20obj%20%3D%20new%20MyClass()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.write(JSON.stringify(obj))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20mail%20%3D%20new%20Main()%3B).

I would like to do the same using a decorator but it doesn't work as [shown here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40enumerable(true)%0D%0Aget%20location()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%27Hello%20from%20Getetr!%27%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Main%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20obj%20%3D%20new%20MyClass()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.write(JSON.stringify(obj))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20enumerable(value%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20function%20(target%3A%20any%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20descriptor%20%3D%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target%2C%20propertyKey)%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(descriptor.enumerable%20!%3D%3D%20value)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20descriptor.enumerable%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(target%2C%20propertyKey%2C%20descriptor)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20mail%20%3D%20new%20Main()%3B).

Please do not suggest implementing the `toJSON` method, I know that it may help but I want a decorators-only solution.

It's also relevant for Angular as I need that to make `formGroup.patchValue` work for getters.

I [updated my example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20@enumerable(true)%0D%0Aget%20location():%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%27Hello%20from%20Getetr!%27%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Main%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20obj%20=%20new%20MyClass();%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.write(JSON.stringify(obj));%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20enumerable(value:%20boolean)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20function%20(target:%20any,%20propertyKey:%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(target.toJSON%20&&%20!target.__propsToMakeEnumerable)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return;%20//%20previously%20existing%20toJSON,%20nothing%20to%20do!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20target.__propsToMakeEnumerable%20=%20target.__propsToMakeEnumerable%20%7C%7C%20%5B%5D;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20descriptor%20=%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target,%20propertyKey)%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(descriptor.enumerable%20!==%20value)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target.__propsToMakeEnumerable.push(%7BpropertyKey,%20value%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20target.toJSON%20=%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20self%20=%20this;%20//%20JSFiddle%20transpiler%20apparently%20is%20not%20transpiling%20arrow%20functions%20properly%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!this.__propsToMakeEnumerableAlreadyProcessed)%20%7B%20//%20so%20we%20just%20do%20this%20once%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%27processing%20non-enumerable%20props...%27);%20//%20remove%20later,%20just%20for%20testing%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20propsToMakeEnumerable%20=%20self.__proto__.__propsToMakeEnumerable;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(propsToMakeEnumerable%20%7C%7C%20%5B%5D).forEach((%7BpropertyKey,%20value%7D)%20=%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20descriptor%20=%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(self.__proto__,%20propertyKey);%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20descriptor.enumerable%20=%20true;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(self,%20propertyKey,%20descriptor);%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(this,%20%27__propsToMakeEnumerableAlreadyProcessed%27,%20%7Bvalue:%20true,%20enumerable:%20false%7D);%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20mail%20=%20new%20Main();) with @acdcjunior suggestion - hope they will find what I am missing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`JSON.stringify()`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-json.stringify), only serializes the object's own enumerable properties. With that decorator you are adding the getters as properties of the prototype object.

From the [ES6 Spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-json.stringify):

> ### 24.3.2.3 Runtime Semantics: SerializeJSONObject ( value )
>
> The abstract operation SerializeJSONObject with argument value
>   serializes an object. It has access to the stack, indent, gap, and
>   PropertyList values of the current invocation of the stringify method.
>
> (...)
>
> - 5. If *PropertyList* is not undefined, then
>
>      - Let K be *PropertyList*.
> - 6. Else,
>
>      - Let K be [EnumerableOwnNames](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-enumerableownnames)(value).

The relevant point is `6`.

If you ask, *PropertyList* is related to the [serialization of arrays](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-json.stringify), so it couldn't be an escape hatch.

---

With a method level decorator, although you said you didn't want it, the only way I can think of is to have the decorator add, if not exists, a `toJSON` to the prototype of the class.

Such `toJSON` would (when first called, only) add the getters from the class prototype (as enumerable properties) to the instance whhich `toJSON` is being called upon.

The tricky part would be, when you have multiple getters decorated, to, when processing the second and on decorators, differentiate if the `toJSON` you have was either created by you (and then you can "append" a property of the current decorator) or if it was in the class originally (in which case you would ignore). Tricky, but, as far as I can tell, doable.

## Demo

Per request, there you go. [**JSFiddle demo here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/tmy771c1/)

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(public name) {}
  @enumerable(true)
    get location(): string {
    return 'Hello from Location!'
  }
  @enumerable(true)
    get age(): number {
    return 12345;
  }
    get sex(): string {
    return "f";
  }
}
class MyClassWithToJson {
  constructor(public name) {}
  @enumerable(true)
    get nickname(): string {
    return 'I shall still be non enumerable'
  }
  toJSON() { return 'Previously existing toJSON()!' }
}

function enumerable(value: boolean) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string) {
      if (!value) {
        // didnt ask to enumerate, nothing to do because even enumerables at the prototype wont
        // appear in the JSON
        return;
      }
        if (target.toJSON && !target.__propsToMakeEnumerable) {
        return; // previously existing toJSON, nothing to do!
      }
      target.__propsToMakeEnumerable = (target.__propsToMakeEnumerable || []).concat([{propertyKey, value}])

      target.toJSON = function () {
        let self = this; // JSFiddle transpiler apparently is not transpiling arrow functions properly
        if (!this.__propsToMakeEnumerableAlreadyProcessed) { // so we just do this once
          console.log('processing non-enumerable props...'); // remove later, just for testing
          let propsToMakeEnumerable = self.__propsToMakeEnumerable;
          (propsToMakeEnumerable || []).forEach(({propertyKey, value}) => {
              let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(self.__proto__, propertyKey);
              descriptor.enumerable = true;
              Object.defineProperty(self, propertyKey, descriptor);
          });
          Object.defineProperty(this, '__propsToMakeEnumerableAlreadyProcessed', {value: true, enumerable: false});
        }
        return this;
      }
  };
}

let obj = new MyClass('Bob');
console.log(JSON.stringify( obj ));
console.log(JSON.stringify( obj )); // this second time it shouldn't print "processing..."
console.log(JSON.stringify( new MyClassWithToJson('MyClassWithToJson') ));
```

Updated [**TypeScript playground link here**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40enumerable(true)%0D%0Aget%20location()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'Hello%20from%20Getetr!'%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Main%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20obj%20%3D%20new%20MyClass()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.write(JSON.stringify(obj))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20enumerable(value%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(target%3A%20any%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!value)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20didnt%20ask%20to%20enumerate%2C%20nothing%20to%20do%20because%20even%20enumerables%20at%20the%20prototype%20wont%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20appear%20in%20the%20JSON%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%09return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(target.toJSON%20%26%26%20!target.__propsToMakeEnumerable)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%3B%20%2F%2F%20previously%20existing%20toJSON%2C%20nothing%20to%20do!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20target.__propsToMakeEnumerable%20%3D%20(target.__propsToMakeEnumerable%20%7C%7C%20%5B%5D).concat(%5B%7B%20propertyKey%2C%20value%20%7D%5D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20target.toJSON%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20self%20%3D%20this%3B%20%2F%2F%20JSFiddle%20transpiler%20apparently%20is%20not%20transpiling%20arrow%20functions%20properly%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!this.__propsToMakeEnumerableAlreadyProcessed)%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20so%20we%20just%20do%20this%20once%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('processing%20non-enumerable%20props...')%3B%20%2F%2F%20remove%20later%2C%20just%20for%20testing%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20propsToMakeEnumerable%20%3D%20self.__propsToMakeEnumerable%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(propsToMakeEnumerable%20%7C%7C%20%5B%5D).forEach((%7BpropertyKey%2C%20value%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20descriptor%20%3D%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(self.__proto__%2C%20propertyKey)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20descriptor.enumerable%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(self%2C%20propertyKey%2C%20descriptor)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(this%2C%20'__propsToMakeEnumerableAlreadyProcessed'%2C%20%7Bvalue%3A%20true%2C%20enumerable%3A%20false%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20mail%20%3D%20new%20Main()%3B).

Comment: Can you share an example based on the code i shared on the links?

Comment: There ya go. Have a look!

Comment: Did you give it a try? Any veredict at all?

Comment: just updated my question with your solution but its not working, could you please look at the link in the last lines of the updated question?

Comment: There you go. Check the updated answer. I pasted a link there at the bottom.

Comment: Ah, and the argument to `@enumerated` is useless. There's no point in using `false` because no getter in the parent will ever appear in the JSON, so there's no need to "turn it off".

Comment: do you know Angular 4? Your solution work perfect only when i'm calling JSON.stringify(obj) before i use formGroup.patchValues(obj). if i call formGroup.patchValues(obj) without calling JSON.stringify(obj) before, Angular not recognize the getters. Is there a way to change the getters to be enumerable while initialize the object and not by calling the toJSON function?

Comment: I believe the only way to get what you want is to use a class-level decorator. Because what you are trying to do requires the instance (which is not available at decorator-time). With a class level decorator you would try to replace the constructor (something [like this](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators/issues/13#issuecomment-189949391)).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm fairly certain you really can't, AFAIK the standard says that `JSON.stringify` will only output an objects *own* enumerable properties.  I think the easiest solution would be to use the second argument of `JSON.stringify` to [pass in the keys you want to whitelist](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%40enumerable(true)%0D%0Aget%20location()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'Hello%20from%20Getetr!'%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Main%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20obj%20%3D%20new%20MyClass()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.write(JSON.stringify(obj%2C%20Object.keys(obj.constructor.prototype)))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20enumerable(value%3A%20boolean)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20function%20(target%3A%20any%2C%20propertyKey%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20descriptor%20%3D%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target%2C%20propertyKey)%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(descriptor.enumerable%20!%3D%3D%20value)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20descriptor.enumerable%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(target%2C%20propertyKey%2C%20descriptor)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20mail%20%3D%20new%20Main()%3B), which will make it use your own list of keys rather than the list which I assume they are getting from `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`:

```
constructor() {
    const obj = new MyClass();
    document.write(JSON.stringify(obj, Object.keys(obj.constructor.prototype)))
}
```